# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, redux-toolkit

I am fetching user details from my Firebase collection users, but when I fetch the data from the users collection it gives me the above error.

> index.esm2017.js:1032 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')

This is the image of my collection:

[image]

Below is my `authslice.js` file. I am checking the currently active user, so I can only show his details on MyProfile page

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  email: null,
  userName: null,
  userID: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    SET_ACTIVE_USER: (state, action) => {
      const { email, userName, userID } = action.payload;
    //   console.log(action.payload);
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.email = email;
      state.userName = userName;
      state.userID = userID;
    },
    REMOVE_ACTIVE_USER(state, action) {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
      state.email = null;
      state.userName = null;
      state.userID = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { SET_ACTIVE_USER, REMOVE_ACTIVE_USER } = authSlice.actions;

export const selectIsLoggedIn = (state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn;
export const selectEmail = (state) => state.auth.email;
export const selectUserName = (state) => state.auth.userName;
export const selectUserID = (state) => state.auth.userID;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

This is my MyProfile Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { db } from "../../Firebase/config";
import { collection, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { selectUserID } from "../../Redux/features/authSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const MyProfile = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const uid = useSelector(selectUserID);

  const getUser = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      // console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data()); 
      const obj = {
        id: uid,
        ...docSnap.data(),
      };
      setUserData(obj);
    } else {
      toast.error("User NOT FOUND ");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Profile</h1>
      {userData && (
        <>
          {/* <img src={userData.photoURL} alt="Profile" /> */}
          <p>Email: {userData.email}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyProfile;
```

How to solve this error? I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is solved guys i just have do this
the details of currently logged in user are stored in my redux store in authSlice
Thanks for answers btw!!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectEmail, selectUserID } from "../../Redux/features/authSlice";

const MyProfile = () => {
  const uid = useSelector(selectUserID);
  const email = useSelector(selectEmail);
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <h1>{uid}</h1>
      <h2>{email}</h2>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyProfile;
```

[image]

big help